Why would a mini PC not support NVME beyond 2TB?
My mini PC came with an M.2 SATA 512GB SSD, but as far as I know, it also supports NVME. Its advertisement says that the maximum is 2TB, but there are 4TB NVME. Is there any technical reason why a mini PC would not support a 4TB NVME? Or is the manufacturer just playing safe, because they didn't test 4TB NVME.

PS: There is not much information about the slot, being a cheap Chinese mini PC on Ali Express. The only more information that might be helpful is that the CPU is Intel Alder Lake N100.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but that says M.2 SSD Max to 2TB - no mention of NVMe in that image

There's Sata only M.2 ports. I learnt this the hard way

The number "2TB" comes from 0xffffffff logical blocks. When the logical block size is 512-byte, the capacity in bytes of that would be 2TiB - 512 byte. (The capacity of "2TB drives" are "way less" than 2TiB.) 0xffffffff is the maximum value that can be represented with a 32-bit unsigned integer. (So it's really a matter of whether the UEFI firmware vendor /devs stupidly uses that for capacity-in-logical-blocks anywhere.)

This is N100, so it was from at least 2023. Do SATA-only M.2 ports still exist? I thought I saw somewhere that it supports NVME, but when I checked it again, I could not find it, so maybe that was for other mini PC's with the same CPU.

I have one that's a generation or two older  (N3350 ) that's sata only - and it kind of makes sense to save money on stocking one type of connector, and only wiring what's needed. I've been bitten on the rear a few times. Its probably less a CPU thing than a motherboard thing, and working out how 'best' to use PCIe lanes

@DamnVegetables - Yes, they do exist.

@DamnVegetables M.2 SATA does still exist and it's common to find motherboards with M.2 supporting both SATA and NVMe on the same port, as using NVMe restricts how many PCIe cards, USB3/C headers/ports, and others can be used, if any, while using NVMe since it uses PCIe lanes, not the SATA controller. TechSpot has an informative write up of how boards assign the 20+ PCIe lanes (they're what a lot of the features on a board run through), and why when enabling NVMe, you often lose at least one PCIe slot on the board, if not more

They are playing it safe.
If there are any issues it will be around the partitioning of the drive and the boot loader.  The old "DOS" style of partitioning hard drives would not support drives more then 2TB - and it is possible that having a boot drive that is larger then 2TB could cause issues.   (This is more likely to be an issue around SATA disks - and M.2 is an implementation of SATA)
I would expect any drive that supports UEFI boot would support larger disks no problem, and I would expect that a system that supports NVME would support UEFI.

Would this answer really apply since NVMe generally can't be found on BIOS motherboards, only UEFI motherboards (it was released in 2011, but I've never come across a motherboard with NVMe SSD support that doesn't have UEFI firmware)? mSATA could be, but even M.2 is likely a UEFI motherboard only form factor implementation since it was released in 2013; most, if not all, consumer motherboards manufactured after ~2014 were UEFI only. In regards to the 2TB maximum of MBR, Windows has supported EFI boot (which requires GPT) since Windows 7, so an MBR limitation also doesn't seem to apply
